# Need to solve Group by

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

```
SELECT WK_NBR,region_cd,plant_cd, POS_GAP_1DAY 
  FROM(SELECT wk_nbr,region_cd,plant_cd, 
       round((CASE WHEN SUM(gap_1day)>0 THEN SUM(gap_1day) ELSE 0 END     ),2) AS POS_GAP_1DAY
       FROM
         table a
       group by wk_nbr,region_cd,plant_cd)
```

In the above query the problem I am facing is `POS_GAP_1DAY` should sum up only the positive numbers in the column but the above query will not give the right answer since I check `SUM(gap_1day)>0`.

The problem is I need to group by only `wk_nbr`,`region_cd`,`plant_cd`.

Please suggest

Answer (score 3):

Try change

```
round((CASE WHEN SUM(gap_1day)>0 THEN SUM(gap_1day) ELSE 0 END     ),2) AS POS_GAP_1DAY
```

to

```
ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN SIGN(gap_1day) > 0 THEN gap_1day ELSE 0 END), 2) AS POS_GAP_1DAY
```

Comment: @Mani You're welcome. Glad it helped :D. And as Davide absolutely correctly commented it seems that your outer select is redundant. Therefore if you don't do anything else with the query get rid of it.

Answer (score 2):

done on the spot, so I don't know if it works, but...

```
 SELECT wk_nbr,region_cd,plant_cd, 
        round(SUM(CASE WHEN GAP_1DAY>0 then GAP_1DAY else 0 end),2) AS POS_GAP_1DAY
   FROM
     table a
   group by wk_nbr,region_cd,plant_cd
```

doesn't do what you want?

Comment: :yes it does :( I am new to SQL. Thank you so much

Comment: just a quick note.. the outer select is redundant in your specific case